# Extracting specific sections of text from simple text files

Tags: python-3.x, text, extract

I'm very much a newbie when it comes to Python and am struggling with the following task. Hoping someone can help.

I have a large number of files that share some common characteristics although not all. Within these files are sections of information that I need to extract but ONLY those sections that contain a specific line of text. This is a snippet of the common text in one of the files:

room 31
name "Bob"
no TV outlet 49
exit
room 5
name "Ted"
service prov 10.1
outlet 49-50,52
exit
room 80
name "Alice"
outlet 49-50,52
dead outlet 1-20
exit
room 50
name "Tim"
outlet 49
exit
room 51
name "Sue"
service prov 10.2.0
outlet 49
exit

What I want to output is any section that contains "service prov" (including any additional text on the same line) so using the above as an example, I need the text staring at "room 5" (the number can vary) up to and including "exit", and the same for "room 51" - like this:

room 5
name "Ted"
service prov 10.1
outlet 49-50,52
exit
room 51
name "Sue"
service prov 10.2.0
outlet 49
exit

What is the simplest way to achieve this, bearing in mind the number of lines in the section can vary and appear at any position inside the original text file?

All suggestions (especially the simple ones) greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: To clarify your input description somewhat:  The input group begins with a line starting with the line beginning with he word 'room' and ending with ta line beginning with the word 'exit'.  You are only interested in documenting group data that contains a line beginning with the key phrase 'service prov'..  Is this a correct description of all filtering characteristics?

Comment: Yes that's right.  The "section" I'm looking for would start with "room", contain "service prov" and end with "exit". Any section starting with "room", ending with "exit" that doesn't contain "service prov" isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a text input of the form described in your question.  Here's how I would do it:

```
def parse_input(in_data):
    start_key = 'room'
    end_key = 'exit'
    trigger_key = 'service prov'
    new_element = False
    trigger_exists = False
    out_data = ''
    element_data = ''
    for line in in_data: 
        if not new_element and start_key == line[:len(start_key)].lower():
            new_element = True
            element_data += f'{line}\n'
        else:
            element_data += f'{line}\n'
            if trigger_key == line[:len(trigger_key)].lower():
                trigger_exists = True
            if end_key == line[:len(end_key)].lower():
                if trigger_exists:
                    out_data += element_data
                trigger_exists = False
                new_element = False
                element_data = ''
    return out_data
```

Executing

```
print(parse_input(lines))
```

Produces:

```
room 5
name "Ted"
service prov 10.1
outlet 49-50,52
exit
room 51
name "Sue"
service prov 10.2.0
outlet 49
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be using a pattern starting matching by room and end matching with exit, while matching service prov in between.

```
^room \d+(?:\n(?!room \d|service prov).*)*\nservice prov.*(?:\n(?!room|exit).*)*\nexit$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^room \d+` Start of string, match `room`  and 1+ digits
- `(?:\n(?!room \d|service prov).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with room and digit or service prov using a negative lookahead `(?!`
- `\nservice prov.*` Match a newline and the whole line with service prove
- `(?:\n(?!room|exit).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with either room of exit using a negative lookahead `(?!`
- `\nexit$` Match a newline, `exit` and assert end of string

Example

```
import re
 
regex = r"^room \d+(?:\n(?!room \d|service prov).*)*\nservice prov.*(?:\n(?!room|exit).*)*\nexit$"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BAPgtT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aZbg10)

```
test_str = ("room 31\n"
    "name \"Bob\"\n"
    "no TV outlet 49\n"
    "exit\n"
    "room 5\n"
    "name \"Ted\"\n"
    "service prov 10.1\n"
    "outlet 49-50,52\n"
    "exit\n"
    "room 80\n"
    "name \"Alice\"\n"
    "outlet 49-50,52\n"
    "dead outlet 1-20\n"
    "exit\n"
    "room 50\n"
    "name \"Tim\"\n"
    "outlet 49\n"
    "exit\n"
    "room 51\n"
    "name \"Sue\"\n"
    "service prov 10.2.0\n"
    "outlet 49\n"
    "exit")
 
print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['room 5\nname "Ted"\nservice prov 10.1\noutlet 49-50,52\nexit', 'room 51\nname "Sue"\nservice prov 10.2.0\noutlet 49\nexit']
```

Comment: itprorh66 & The fourth bird,

Thanks for the assistance, greatly appreciated. Sorry to take so long to respond - too much to do, never enough time.

@ itprorh66,

I was a little puzzled by the code (new to coding in general) as it didn't work at first.  I worked through it line by line and then realised that the text had to be split into lines before it would work. Once I added the splitlines() function to the code, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

@ The fourth bird,

Comment: itprorh66 & The fourth bird,

Thanks for the assistance, greatly appreciated. Sorry to take so long to respond - too much to do, never enough time.

@ itprorh66,

I was a little puzzled by the code (new to coding in general) as it didn't work at first.  I worked through it line by line and then realised that the text had to be split into lines before it would work. Once I added the splitlines() function to the code, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

@ The fourth bird,

Yours worked as well although getting my head around the regex in that filter... I've still got the headache! Thanks!